# Facebook Open Graph API share give different result between Javascript SDK and Graph Explorer Tool

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share image that I have uploaded to facebook first to user status.

When I'm using Graph Explorer tools, I got the correct display that I want (which is my image along side description I put)
[image: Graph Explorer]

[image: Graph Explorer result]

But when I run it from my web using Javascript SDK, it gives me different result.
[image: Javascript SDK result]

This is the code that I use:

```
FB.api(
    '/me/feed',
    'POST',
    { 
       "picture": "http://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/18119081_10208875702785289_5723991364540686560_n.jpg?oh=4184d29286453c6b8d924d4e6332873f&oe=598B2D91", 
       "name": "I’ve just designed my dream stroller!", 
       "description": "I’ve just designed my dream stroller!", 
       "link": "https://thebabyclub.co/baby-stroller-online" 
    },
    function (result) {
       console.log(result);
       if (result && !result.error) {
            console.log("Posted image to facebook");
       }
    }
 );
```

It's been bugging me for several days. Please kindly advise, if anyone has similar experience like this before.

Comment: Facebook is in the process of removing all possibilities to set these values at runtime, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations In the near future, only the Open Graph meta data the URL returns will be taken into account. If you want to share with different title, description or thumbnail, you will have to create an individual URL for that each time.

Comment: @CBroe I see now. But then is that individual URL need to exist after I share it to Facebook? I'm thinking if that's the case, then I'll just create a page that I can dynamically change the Open Graph metadata. Will it works?

Comment: Facebook will re-crawl shared URLs in regular intervals. But if you use some sort of URL with GET parameters (id to look up values in database, or sth. like that), it should be no big problem to provide the data permanently.